# SQL Azure Stored Procedure Multiple result sets

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, subquery, azure-sql-database

I am creating a stored procedure for initial page load and thus have two different queries and result sets.

The first query is entirely repeated as a nested `SELECT` inside the second query.

My question then is whether to put the results of the first query into a table var or to just essentially duplicate the code/query in the second query?

Thanks in advance.

```
--Get Most Popular Sports for each country
    SELECT
        dbo.Countries2Sports.rank,
        dbo.Countries2Sports.SportName,
        dbo.Countries2Sports.imageURL,
        dbo.Countries2Sports.imageALTtext
    FROM
        dbo.Countries2Sports
    WHERE
        dbo.Countries2Sports.CountryCode = @CountryCode
    ORDER BY
        dbo.Countries2Sports.rank ASC

    --Get Organizations related to each country's sports
    SELECT
        dbo.Countries2Organizations.ID,
        dbo.Countries2Organizations.OrganizationCode,
        dbo.Countries2Organizations.OrganizationName,
        dbo.Countries2Organizations.LogoURL,
        dbo.Countries2Organizations.Sport
    FROM
        dbo.Countries2Organizations
    WHERE
        dbo.Countries2Organizations.Sport IN 
            (
                SELECT
                    dbo.Countries2Sports.SportName
                FROM
                    dbo.Countries2Sports
                WHERE
                    dbo.Countries2Sports.CountryCode = @CountryCode
            )
      AND (dbo.Countries2Organizations.CountryCode = @CountryCode OR 
           dbo.Countries2Organizations.CountryCode = '')
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code of stored prod? Explanation of use car would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want result sets in output then you can use CTE which will be better than temp table if number of records are low as below:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        dbo.Countries2Sports.rank,
        dbo.Countries2Sports.SportName,
        dbo.Countries2Sports.imageURL,
        dbo.Countries2Sports.imageALTtext

    FROM
        dbo.Countries2Sports
    WHERE
        dbo.Countries2Sports.CountryCode = @CountryCode
    --ORDER BY
    --    dbo.Countries2Sports.rank ASC
)
--Get Organizations related to each country's sports
SELECT
    dbo.Countries2Organizations.ID,
    dbo.Countries2Organizations.OrganizationCode,
    dbo.Countries2Organizations.OrganizationName,
    dbo.Countries2Organizations.LogoURL,
    dbo.Countries2Organizations.Sport
FROM
    dbo.Countries2Organizations
WHERE
    dbo.Countries2Organizations.Sport IN 
        (
            SELECT
                dbo.Countries2Sports.SportName
            FROM
                CTE
        )
AND (   dbo.Countries2Organizations.CountryCode = @CountryCode  OR dbo.Countries2Organizations.CountryCode = '')
```

Comment: Thanks.  To be honest I don't know if I want different result sets -- at present the first result set populates one set of icons while the second result set populates an entirely different component of the web page.  Thus to my inexperienced eye a combined result set just seems extra work for the front end to parse . . .